# Adjusting the font size used for paragraph in tiny mce plugin

Tags: tinymce

I used TINY_MCE plugin to have an advanced editor. The problem is that the default font used in this plugin is **too small** for me. Is it possible to change it? I mean the default font used for paragraph. As you can see below, the font is smaller that the font I used for other fields.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not that difficult. The easiest was will be to use the tinymce init paramter [content_css](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=tinymce%20custom_css&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css&ei=JzsZT7z1BMyc-waKpcHACg&usg=AFQjCNHRf68oWTuTvu6uIgl_P1qEBciJ_g&cad=rja)

```
//css file, which will overwrite the default css settings for the editors itframe
content_css: 'my_css_file.css',
```

in this ccs file you need to set

```
p {
    font-size: 30px; // or whtever you like
}
```

Comment: On my wishlist would be having that default font size be a primary configuration variable.  Creating a new css file to handle font size is obnoxious.